# Should a Brahmin who work for wage be considered as brahmin?

Tags: brahmins, shudra

If a Brahmin man work for wage (a shura attribute) , should he be considered as Brahman ?

I had read somewhere that no matter what a brahmin man does, even if he indulges in wrongful things , he should always be considered as Brahmin .

Comment: The last line is absolutely nonsense. If a brahmaṇa skips the 3 Sandhyavandanas continously for 3 days, he becomes a śūdra.

Comment: Please accept the answer below (and others that you haven’t accepted), else please notify that you won’t be accepting it, if possible giving a reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

According to scriptures a Brahmin can earn money only through gifts he receives. He is not even allowed to teach Vedas for wages. Some acts that lead a Brahmin to lose his caste are:

> Manu Smriti 11.61. Defiling a damsel, usury, breaking a vow, selling a
> tank, a garden, one’s wife, or child,
>
> 11.62. Living as a Vratya, casting off a relative, teaching (the Veda) for wages, learning (the Veda) from a paid teacher, and selling goods
> which one ought not to sell,
>
> 11.66. Stealing grain, base metals, or cattle, intercourse with women who drink spirituous liquor, slaying women, Sudras, Vaisyas, or
> Kshatriyas, and atheism, (are all) minor offences, causing loss of
> caste (Upapataka)

However, when in distress and unable to maintain oneself through the lawful occupations, a Brahmin is allowed to resort to a Kshatriya or even a Vaishya mode of living and Vaishyas are allowed to work for wages.

> Manu Smriti 10.80. Among the several occupations the most commendable are, teaching the Veda for a Brahmana, protecting (the people) for a
> Kshatriya, and trade for a Vaisya.
>
> 10.81. But a Brahmana, unable to subsist by his peculiar occupations just mentioned, may live according to the law applicable to
> Kshatriyas; for the latter is next to him in rank.
>
> 10.82. If it be asked, ’How shall it be, if he cannot maintain himself by either (of these occupations?’ the answer is), he may adopt a
> Vaisya’s mode of life, employing himself in agriculture and rearing
> cattle.

In general, while in distress, all men are allowed to work for wages.

> Manu Smriti 10.116. Learning, mechanical arts, work for wages,
> service, rearing cattle, traffic, agriculture, contentment (with
> little), alms, and receiving interest on money, are the ten modes of
> subsistence (permitted to all men in times of distress).